# Can not capture video using OpenCV

Tags: opencv

I installed OpenCV 2.3.1 in my Raspberry Pi (Debian Wheezy) [following this tutorial.](http://eduardofv.com/read_post/185-Installing-OpenCV-on-the-Raspberry-Pi)

But I can't take video using my USB webcam. Gstreamer shows this error:

```
OpenCV Error: Unsupported format or combination of formats (Gstreamer Opencv backend doesn't support this codec acutally.) in CvVideoWriter_GStreamer::open, file /home/pi/OpenCV-2.3.1/modules/highgui/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp, line 483 terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception' what(): /home/pi/OpenCV-2.3.1/modules/highgui/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp:483: error: (-210) Gstreamer Opencv backend doesn't support this codec acutally. in function CvVideoWriter_GStreamer::open Aborted
```

What can I do next?

Comment: What webcam are you using?

Comment: Hi, I am using e-CAM30_USB module. I can take images with this camera. I am using raspberry pi with Debian Wheezy. FFMPEG is ON. Still I am facing problem. Please help me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The gstreamer tells you the stream is unsupported. FFMPEG is on like you said.

I had a look at the camera specifications- it comes out of laptop and is intended to work with Microsoft Windows mostly and not really supported for Linux but they say it will work on Redhat 2.+

That camera returns video in on of these codecs

- YUY2 (FFMPEG OFF?)
- MJPEG  (FFMPEG ON?)

The still pictures is a standard JPG encoded by the MJPEG encoder, that's why you can see it. I am sure gstreamer supports MJPEG  and not sure about YUV2. But! It is possible that the MJPEG implementation for ARM (Pi) architecture could still not be supported.

Possibly gstreamer needs to ask the camera for MJPEG directly or something else needs to ask for it. I doubt YUY2 will work any good on the Pi.(At least it is not listed in any supported codecs - but MJPG is)

It is possible that you should use something other than gstreamer. [Take a look here.](http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=38&t=15369&start=25) or [at this post.](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mjpg-streamer/forums/forum/739917/topic/5492659)

### EDIT

OP resolved the problem by using `image 2012-09-18-wheezy-raspbian` and installing `OpenCV 2.4.2` using this extensive and long [guide](http://mitchtech.net/raspberry-pi-opencv/).

Comment: What do you guys mean by FFMPEG is on/off?

Comment: The camera has a setting somewhere to choose the video format. YUY2 is uncompressed, faster and better quality. Enabling this MPEG feature most likley tries to transport the video using MJPEG(which are series of JPG files not really a sophisticated video format) So maybe using gstreamer is not the solution!

Comment: Hi,

  I have much pleasure to inform you, the problem is over. 

  What I done is,

  1. I installed new image 2012-09-18-wheezy-raspbian.img on my raspberry pi.

     Ref: http://elinux.org/RPi_Easy_SD_Card_Setup

  2. Then installed OpenCV 2.4.2 following the site
    
     Ref: http://mitchtech.net/raspberry-pi-opencv/

  Now I can take video with logitech hd720p usb webcam.

   Thanks to your support.

  But I am interested to know why this task shows problems in opencv 2.3.1.

Comment: Hi,Mr ppumkin, I tried to take images with econ Ecam-32 web cam using mjpg-streamer as you said but still I got bad images while logitech cam is working well. Ref: http://www.tanzilli.com/video_streaming.Can we do something else?

Answer (score 1):

Raspberry pi is working with e-con ECAM 32 web cam now. I changed the  voltage regulator which delivering 3.3v to camera , and connected TPS736xx voltage regulator from Texas instruments and now camera taking 320x240 pixel images and video...

Thank you very much for you supports...